# Spotify App API memory leak

Tags: spotify

I'm currently building an app using the Spotify API and some timed requests to my backend. The app proved to have an unlimited consumption on memory over time. I isolated the following code snippet

```
var player = models.player;
var leakTimer=setInterval(leak,500)
function leak(){
    player.playing=true;
}
```

Each call to the function will increase the memory used by Spotify. I stopped the test after 1.5Gb used but it was still increasing. Is that a bug or my mistake ?

Running on OSX 10.7.3, Spotify 0.8.2.610.

Thanks,

Hugo

Answer (score 0):

Intresting... I tested it to and I seem to have the same problem. Everytime I press next song, it will keep rising the memory usage.

I've tested it also with Spotify without my app. Same problem. 
Tested it without any app at all. No problem.

You might wanna test you app without any other app enabled (Last.FM, Tune Wiki etc.) to test if it actually causes leaks. My app does by the way.

I think I know why it is caused though. In my app I will give information about the current playing song with the Last.FM api allong with some other functionalities. When a new song starts the info divs will be emptied, and new information is appended. However, earlier called information seems to be stored somewhere. This will stack up memory usage.

I hope this gives more you more insight. Also, thanks for pointing out.